# GWT: What user.agent is my browser using?

Tags: gwt

I am using GWT 2.5 and GWT 2.7.  I suspect that am running into a bug caused by GWT selecting the wrong `user.agent` property.  How can I see what `user.agent` property GWT has selected?

Ideally, I would like be able to open my browsers developer tools and enter something like `window.gwtProperties.getUserAgent`.  This would return one of the values that I have specifide in the `user.agent` my `something.gwt.xml` file.

Starting point: I know in GWT 2.5 the user agent is selected by UserAgentPropertyGenerator.  This writes a javascript function to *somewhere* that is executed and determines what `user.agent` is used.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xsiframe` linker (used by default in 2.7) will output a `compilation-mappings.txt` file mapping each permutation strong name (equivalent o a generated `*.cache.js` file) to the permutation property values. So looking at which file has been loaded by your browser, you can easily track back which `user.agent` was computed and used.